# Как заполнить массив char

Tags: c++, char, struct

Как заполнить массив char?

```
struct spisok
{
    char fio[50];
    int ng;
};

void fillstr(spisok *a)
{
    a->fio="sdfsdf";//-не заполняет
    a->ng = 624402;
}

void main()
{
    spisok student[5];
    fillstr(student);
}
```

Comment: strcpy(), если у вас там char[]. Либо объявляйте как std::string и тогда оператор = будет работать.

Comment: @Abyx видимо, студийное расширение. Кол-во дополнительных сигнатур `main` определяется реализацией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(a->fio,"sdfsdf");
```

Но лучше

```
strcpy_s(a->fio,50,"sdfsdf"); // В стиле С
```

или (правда, не уверен в стандартности... но в VC++2015 есть):

```
strcpy_s(a->fio,"sdfsdf"); // В стиле С++, если передаете не указатель, а именно массив
```

А еще лучше, раз уж у вас C++ -

```
struct spisok
{
    string fio;
    int ng;

};
void fillstr(spisok *a)
{
    a->fio="sdfsdf";
    a->ng = 624402;

}
```